# Better way of communicating with child components

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, ionic4

I have a `reservation page` which extends an `ReservationController` where I include `reservation-cards` which html look like this:

```
<div class="reservation-card padding-b">
  <mm-list-card [restaurant]="restaurant" [reservation]="true"></mm-list-card>
  <div class="reservation-info">
    <mm-reservation-info 
        [status]="status" 
        [reservationDetails]="reservationDetails"
        (_cancelReservation)="cancelReservation()"></mm-reservation-info>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see I have an output on the `reservation-info` component

The reservation-info component has a cancel button which looks like this (Not the whole component but enough for the example):

```
<p *ngIf="active" class="n-margin xs-margin-t" (click)="cancelReservation()"><a>cancel</a></p>
```

as you see it has a function `cancelReservation()` is there an other way than output and emit the function two times to delete it from the data array of the `ReservationController` in the reservation page?

The data array in the controller looks like this:

```
savedData = {
    newData: [],
    reservation: []
};
```

If I extend the `ReservationController` in the reservation-info it creates a new instance and the data in the array is empty.

So whats the best way to do this? As I think emitting an output method multiple times isn't the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: you can use services and Observables, but I think you should start looking into the state management like NgRx. it's a big jump but it worth.

Comment: for more info on observables ,please refer here:-https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular